# Query for Edges in ArangoDB with Java throws Gson exception

Tags: java, gson, arangodb

I'm new to ArangoDB and trying to do a few very basic queries. I was successful to add vertices and edges, but the query retrieving edges always throws an exception. I tried a few different queries from the (very minimalistic) documentation and it always throws the same. Here is one of the queries:

```
CursorEntity<BaseDocument> r = arangoDriver.graphGetEdges("MyGraph", BaseDocument.class, "Person/1");
while (r.iterator().hasNext()){
    BaseDocument d = r.iterator().next();
    System.out.println(d.getDocumentHandle());
}
```

Or this one with the same exception:

```
String query = "for i in GRAPH_EDGES(@graphName, @vertexId, {direction: 'outbound', edgeCollectionRestriction: 'Friends'}) return i";
    Map<String, Object> bindVars = new MapBuilder().put("graphName", "MyGraph").put("vertexId", "Person/1").get();
    CursorEntity<PlainEdgeEntity> result;
    try {
        result = arangoDriver.executeQuery(query, bindVars, PlainEdgeEntity.class ,true, 10);
```

And here the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING
at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:868)
at com.google.gson.Gson$1.deserialize(Gson.java:126)
at com.arangodb.entity.EntityDeserializers$CursorEntityDeserializer.deserialize(EntityDeserializers.java:519)
at com.arangodb.entity.EntityDeserializers$CursorEntityDeserializer.deserialize(EntityDeserializers.java:488)
at com.google.gson.TreeTypeAdapter.read(TreeTypeAdapter.java:58)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
at com.arangodb.entity.EntityFactory.createEntity(EntityFactory.java:109)
at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntityImpl(BaseArangoDriver.java:270)
at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntity(BaseArangoDriver.java:181)
at com.arangodb.BaseArangoDriver.createEntity(BaseArangoDriver.java:219)
at com.arangodb.impl.InternalCursorDriverImpl.executeQuery(InternalCursorDriverImpl.java:78)
at com.arangodb.ArangoDriver.executeQuery(ArangoDriver.java:1877)
at com.arangodb.ArangoDriver.graphGetEdges(ArangoDriver.java:4135)
at x.y.z.database.arangodb.Arango.main(Arango.java:34)
```

I almost think it is a bug? Maybe a problem with newest versions? Or do i miss something?

Using latest versions.. 2.6.8 and driver 2.5.7

**Update:** if I use a nonexistent ID it returns zero results without exception and if i use an existing ID the same exception is thrown. that tells me that i used the right parameters, and the problem is most likely a bug..

Comment: can you have a look in the ArangoDB Webinterface, whether the collections and the graph exists?

Comment: Are you sure a graph named `MyGraph` does actually exist in the database you're querying in the database that the driver is using when the queries are failing? I'm asking because I tried the above code (first example) and it worked for me. I used ArangoDB 2.6.8 and the Java driver's latest master (git commit d73f91f8226182584a6e0eb6f881caeabd38072b). I used ArangoDB's web interface to manually create a graph named `MyGraph` in the default `_system` database. Running the code from the 1st example returns an empty array for me, but no exception. So it looks ok. Which driver version do you use?

Comment: @dothebart yes it exists i was able to add them programatically, and can query them over the console.

Comment: @stj yes it all exists. its interesting, if i type in an id that doesn't exist, it returns an empty array too and NO EXCEPTION. Only if i query for something that actually exists it throws an exception.
i got the driver via maven, just downloaded it yesterday, it says driver version 2.4
maybe its an old version in the maven repo? unfortunately they don't have a simple jar file to download on their website with the newest driver.

Comment: i updated the driver to the latest version 2.5.7 but still the same.. some functions that i got from the docs are now deprecated, but everything else works the same. if i type in a nonexistent ID it returns zero results and if i use an existing ID the same exception is thrown..

Comment: I was able to reproduce the exception now. It is caused by the `graphGetEdges` method in the driver not setting a specific flag in the AQL query it sends to the server to retrieve the edges. The server can return two result formats, one containing just ids of found documents, and the other to also include all other attributes. The server-side default has changed in 2.6.0, and the driver still expected the pre-2.6 format. I have adjusted the driver so it sends the required flag so it works now: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/commit/78b6fe7dbadf63b27ae64de16d111b318990875a

Comment: Btw. I have also bumped the driver's version number, which was still 2.5-ish. It is now 2.6-ish as expected. I think we also need to build some ready-to-use jars for the driver and upload them to the central maven repository. I don't have access to that myself, so I've asked a colleague to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for this quick response and fix, but unfortunately it doesn't fix it for me. In the first code example the iterator gives back an endless loop, i need to kill the server, and in the second code example the same error message persists.

Comment: However, i noticed that both functions .graphGetEdges() and .executeQuery() are deprecated. Your Java documentations are unfortunetally not helpful in this case. I'm looking for a simple .getObjectById(id) functionality that works with a generic class as a result, without the Object mapping to a customized class.

Comment: another small feedback/request.. it would be absolutely awesome if the .jar file could be directly available for download. you won't believe but there are still some projects out there in the java world who don't use maven in their project. ;) of course its easy to create an empty project with maven to get the jar.. but to be able to just download it either from github or from your website would be awesome ;)

Comment: There's a driver release fixing the initial problem: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/releases . That should work fine with the following code: `CursorEntity<BaseDocument> r = driver.graphGetEdges("myGraph", BaseDocument.class, "Person/1"); Iterator<BaseDocument> it = r.iterator(); while { it.hasNext()) { BaseDocument d = it.next(); System.out.println(d.getDocumentHandle()); }`
The example code `while (r.iterator().hasNext()) { ... }` won't work because it will create a new Iterator object in each iteration and thus never finish.

Comment: The .jar files are published via Maven's central repo: http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg:%22com.arangodb%22%20AND%20a:%22arangodb-java-driver%22 I think the .jars can be downloaded from there directly, without using mvn.

Comment: Did the answers fullfill your needs? If not, whats missing? If, can you mark it accepted?

Answer (score 2):

As stj pointed out, there's a driver release fixing the initial problem: http://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/releases .

That should work fine with the following code:

```
CursorEntity<BaseDocument> r = driver.graphGetEdges("myGraph",
                               BaseDocument.class, "Person/1"); 
Iterator<BaseDocument> it = r.iterator();
while {
 it.hasNext()) {
   BaseDocument d = it.next();
   System.out.println(d.getDocumentHandle());
 }
}
```

The example code `while (r.iterator().hasNext()) { ... }` won't work because it will create a new Iterator object in each iteration and thus never finish

We added more examples howto work with ArangoDB graphs in java to the  [`learn more` section of the README](https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb-java-driver/#learn-more)